# LINQ "zip" in String Array

Tags: c#, linq

Say there are two arrays:

```
String[] title = { "One","Two","three","Four"};
String[] user = { "rob","","john",""};
```

I need to filter out the above array when the `user` value is Empty then join or zip the two together. Final Output should be like:

```
{ "One:rob", "three:john" }
```

How can this be done using LINQ?

Comment: `Zip` is now a standard method as of .NET 4.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want to "zip" the data together (not join) - i.e. match pairwise; is that correct? If so, simply:

```
    var qry = from row in title.Zip(user, (t, u) => new { Title = t, User = u })
              where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.User)
              select row.Title + ":" + row.User;
    foreach (string s in qry) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

using the `Zip` operation from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx):

```
// http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>
(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
    if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
    if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");
    return ZipIterator(first, second, resultSelector);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipIterator<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>
    (IEnumerable<TFirst> first,
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
            yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
}
```

Comment: Oops I have not formed the example well, Values in both the array wont match at all. Please refer the updated Question.

Comment: I realised that; replaced with "zip"

Comment: it seems a pretty safe canonical example ;-p

Comment: Looks like I need to go long way in LINQ. Thanks for the Example that works.

Comment: Yeah, my goal is to have Marc and Jon post the exact answer that I would have so that I don't have to. Saves me time. Thanks guys!

Comment: @EricLippert, there are room for other Linq answers such as an indexed `Select` and `Aggregate` to achieve the zip; it must have been late in the day for all three of you guys. ;-)  I provide two *alternate* answers for using `Zip`.

Answer (score 9):

For a start, you need a `Zip` operator to zip the two arrays together. Here's an abbreviated version of the code from [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx) (no error checking in this version, just for brevity):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>
    (this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, 
    IEnumerable<TSecond> second, 
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector) 
{
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
            while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
                yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
}
```

Note that `Zip` will be in the standard libraries for .NET 4.0.

Then you need to just apply a filter and a projection. So we'd get:

```
var results = title.Zip(user, (Title, User) => new { Title, User })
                   .Where(x => x.Title != "")
                   .Select(x => x.Title + ":" + x.User);
```

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to the already posted answers, here is a solution without using the Zip method. This assumes that both arrays is of same length.

```
        var pairs = from idx in Enumerable.Range(0, title.Length)
                    let pair = new {Title = title[idx], User = user[idx]}
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(pair.User)
                    select String.Format("{0}:{1}", pair.Title, pair.User);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of .net Core 3.0 and up, the `Zip` extension method is now built in.

```C#
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);

foreach (var item in numbersAndWords)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

```
// This code produces the following output:

// 1 one
// 2 two
// 3 three
```

See more examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

As another addition to the previous answers, Zip is usually defined and used in conjunction with a `Tuple` type. This relieves the user of having to provide a `resultSelector` function.

```
public class Tuple<TItem1, TItem2> // other definitions for higher arity
{
    public TItem1 Item1 { get; private set; }
    public TItem2 Item2 { get; private set; }

    public Tuple(TItem1 item1, TItem2 item2)
    {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item2;
    }
}
```

And hence:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>> Zip<TFirst, TSecond>
    (this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second) 
{
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
            yield return new Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>(e1.Current, e2.Current);
    }
}
```

I believe this is closer to what CLR 4.0 will have (though it may have the more flexible variety as well).

Answer (score 0):

In looking at Marc's answer (and ultimately the `Zip` method as of .Net 4), there is a significant amount of overhead to enumerate and join of rows where they are eventually thrown away; can that be done without that waste?

In looking at Jon's answer, creating a projection of dynamic entities to reference the existing data and then creating a new set of entities from that mirror could be a deterrent to using that method if the total row count were overly large.

The below snippet uses the references to the original data and the only *wasted* projected entitles created are the ones which have null string which are subsequently removed. Also the enumeration of the data is kept to a minimum.

```
String[] title = { "One","Two","three","Four"};
String[] user  = { "rob","","john",""};

user.Select ((usr, index) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(usr) 
                             ? string.Empty 
                             : string.Format("{0}:{1}", title[index], usr ))
    .Where (cmb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb) == false)
```

As an aside, this methodology could have user array which is smaller in size than the title array as a plus.

---

The `Aggregate` function is overlooked, here it is in action:

```
int index = 0;
user.Aggregate (new List<string>(), 
                (result, usr) => 
                     {  
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usr) == false)
                           result.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", title[index], usr));
                        ++index;
                        return result;
                      } )
```