# C# - combining collections question

Tags: c#, linq, collections, merge

If I have a `IDictionary<int, int>`, is it possible to receive a `IEnumerable<int>`, which
would contain every `KeyValuePair<int, int>` disassembled into two `(int, int)` entries inserted one after another?

*Small example:*

```
Dictionary:
5 - 25
6 - 36
7 - 49

Wanted Enumerable:
5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49
```

*Also, I wanted to have this in one super-pretty statement, but I couldn't think of an appropriate one :)*

---

**Update:**

Does `LINQ` allow to insert more than one element per `.Select` statement, something sharing the idea of:

```
xyz.Select(t => (t, null))
```

so that the resulting `Enumerable` would contain both `t` and `null` right after it?

Comment: Whatever solution you pick, keep in mind that a dictionary makes no guarantees about the order of enumeration. So, in your example, you could get "6, 36, 5, 25, 7, 49" instead. If you do want some order, you can use OrderBy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) (plus overloads). Here's an example

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int> {
   { 5, 25 },
   { 6, 36 },
   { 7, 49 } 
}; 

var projection = dict.SelectMany(kv => new[] { kv.Key, kv.Value });
```

As per the comments, this is just one way of achieving what you have asked.

Comment: Not really, bu you _could_ (ab)use `dict.SelectMany(kvp => new [] { kvp.Key, kvp.Value })` provided that an enumerated type could be inferred for both Key and Value type

Comment: Maybe not the ideal use case for `SelectMany` but relatively clean and understandable, provided as you say, the enumerated type could be inferred.

Comment: +1: This looks a little hacky, but it's what I would do and certainly it's the only way to do what is asked with the built-in methods.

Comment: Thinking about it, even if the type couldn't be inferred, you'd have to coerce the types to a "common type denominator" in the delegate/lambda, which you'd have to do in any case to enumerate over all keys and values using one iterator block, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a method that will decompose your dictionary into an IEnumerable in the way you want.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class C {

    public static void Main()
    {
        var dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();
        dic[0] = 1;
        dic[2] = 3;
        dic[4] = 5;

        foreach (var i in Decompose(dic))
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> Decompose(IDictionary<int,int> dic)
    {
        foreach (var i in dic.Keys)
        {
            yield return i;
            yield return dic[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
```

Comment: +1 for having a simple solution that does *what was asked* and not something similar (or not even close in some cases).

Answer (score 2):

I'd think of this as

```
var enumerable = Mix(dict.Keys, dict.Values);
```

I believe in .NET framework 4.0 Enumerable.Zip comes close[1]

So I've found time to implement this**MixSequences** method, *Note how just for fun I made it n-ary, so it will combine any number of sequences (not just 2).*

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NS
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<T> MixSequences<T> (params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
        {
            var se = sequences.Select(s => s.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
            try
            {
                while (se.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
                    foreach (var v in se.Select(e => e.Current))
                        yield return v;
            }
            finally
            { se.ForEach(e => e.Dispose()); }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int,int>{ {1,4},{13,8},{2,1} };
            var twin = new Dictionary<int,int>{ {71,74},{83,78},{72,71} };

            Console.WriteLine("Keys: {0}", string.Join(", ", dict.Keys));
            Console.WriteLine("Values: {0}", string.Join(", ", dict.Values));
            Console.WriteLine("Proof of pudding: {0}", string.Join(", ", MixSequences(dict.Keys, dict.Values)));
            Console.WriteLine("For extra super fun: {0}", string.Join(", ", MixSequences(dict.Keys, twin.Keys, dict.Values, twin.Values)));
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

[1] *Update* See [here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176653/linq-zip-in-string-array) for background.

Comment: -1: This isn't what `Zip` does. This example would do what you intended it to do with `Concat` instead of `Zip`.

Comment: I think the OP wants the resulting sequence to have 6 elements (5, 25, 6, 36, 7, 49), not three elements that are pairs.

Comment: @Jon - Concat will give you 5,6,7,25,36,49.

Comment: @TrueWill: I know -- `SelectMany` is the answer here. But `Concat` is what I think the person writing this had in mind.

Comment: Hehe what misinformation. @Jon: Zip is _not_ concat. @Martinho: spot on. Incidentally I posted the selectmany version before this [as a comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452687/c-combining-collections-question/5452705#5452705). WIll update the answer with better info + links

Comment: I added a compiling example of what I _meant_ the first time round. If on C# 3.5 (or before?) you'll probably have to add `.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray()` inside the string.Join calls :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use following methods:

```
var list = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
var list2 = dictionary.Values.ToList();
```

you can join this lists in one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a object/collection/what have you using LINQ.  Say you want to merge two very different/unrelated (or barely related) items into one (pseudo code follows):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> newList = (from a in AList
                                              select new KeyValuePair<string, string> 
                                              {
                                                a,
                                                getBfromA(a)
                                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

> dict.Select(d => new[] { d.Key, d.Value }).SelectMany(d => d)