# Is there a way to add two multi line strings together?

Tags: c#

```
string usernamesfile = File.ReadAllText(openusername.FileName);
string passwordsfile = File.ReadAllText(openpassword.FileName);
```

I would like to read from both text files and combine all lines together with ":" dividing them:

Basically:

```
line:line
line2:line2
```

Thanks =)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, if both files have the same number of rows

```
        // assumed file strings
        var usernames = "Username1\n" + 
                        "Username2\n" +
                        "username3";
        var passwords = "Password1\n" +
                        "Password2\n" +
                        "Password3";
        // Split it for each line
        var usernamesfile = usernames.Split("\n"); 
        var passwordsfile = passwords.Split("\n");
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < usernamesfile.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{usernamesfile[i]}:{passwordsfile[i]}");
        }

        // Username1:Password1
        // Username2:Password2
        // username3:Password3
        var bothLines = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: The correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176653/linq-zip-in-string-array